# Is there an alternative to the Adventureworks database for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

I want to use something lighter than adventureworks. Is there an alternative at all? I have had a look at the Chinook database, but I just want see if there is an alternative. Google search doesn't help either.

Comment: I am looking for a sample sql server database other than Adventureworks 2008.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/wide-world-importers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server Community Projects & Samples](http://www.codeplex.com/SqlServerSamples)

[Microsoft SQL Server Product Samples: Databases](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples)

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid. Until now I assumed that codeplex only had MS databases like adventureworks and northwind.